# Failed to install dev-python/six-1.10.0

Tags: software-installation, gentoo, chrome-os

I have chrome OS.

Linux localhost 4.4.64-09100-g30321742b4e0 #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 21 20:08:24 PDT 2017 x86_64 Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU N4200 @ 1.10GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

and I have problem for command "dev_install" or "emerge @world -e"

```
Installing (1 of 13) dev-python/six-1.10.0::portage-stable to /usr/local/
 * Running stacked hooks for pre_pkg_preinst
 *    wrap_old_config_scripts ...                                                                                                     [ ok ]
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
ImportError: No module named site
 * ERROR: dev-python/six-1.10.0::portage-stable failed (preinst phase):
 *   (no error message)
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line   94:  Called pkg_preinst
 *   environment, line 2805:  Called python_foreach_impl '_cleanup'
 *   environment, line 3464:  Called multibuild_foreach_variant '_python_multibuild_wrapper' '_cleanup'
 *   environment, line 2466:  Called _multibuild_run '_python_multibuild_wrapper' '_cleanup'
 *   environment, line 2464:  Called _python_multibuild_wrapper '_cleanup'
 *   environment, line  602:  Called python_wrapper_setup
 *   environment, line 3863:  Called python_export 'python2.7' 'PYTHON_CONFIG'
 *   environment, line 3223:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *                           flags=$("${PYTHON}" -c 'import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var("ABIFLAGS") or "")') || die;
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-python/six-1.10.0::portage-stable'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-python/six-1.10.0::portage-stable'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/usr/local/var/tmp/portage/dev-python/six-1.10.0/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/usr/local/var/tmp/portage/dev-python/six-1.10.0/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/usr/local/lib/portage/pym'
 * S: '/usr/local/var/tmp/portage/dev-python/six-1.10.0/work/six-1.10.0'
!!! FAILED preinst: 1

>>> Failed to install dev-python/six-1.10.0 to /usr/local/, Log file:

>>>  '/usr/local/var/tmp/portage/dev-python/six-1.10.0/temp/build.log'

 * Messages for package dev-python/six-1.10.0 merged to /usr/local/:

 * ERROR: dev-python/six-1.10.0::portage-stable failed (preinst phase):
 *   (no error message)
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line   94:  Called pkg_preinst
 *   environment, line 2805:  Called python_foreach_impl '_cleanup'
 *   environment, line 3464:  Called multibuild_foreach_variant '_python_multibuild_wrapper' '_cleanup'
 *   environment, line 2466:  Called _multibuild_run '_python_multibuild_wrapper' '_cleanup'
 *   environment, line 2464:  Called _python_multibuild_wrapper '_cleanup'
 *   environment, line  602:  Called python_wrapper_setup
 *   environment, line 3863:  Called python_export 'python2.7' 'PYTHON_CONFIG'
 *   environment, line 3223:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *                           flags=$("${PYTHON}" -c 'import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_config_var("ABIFLAGS") or "")') || die;
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=dev-python/six-1.10.0::portage-stable'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=dev-python/six-1.10.0::portage-stable'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/usr/local/var/tmp/portage/dev-python/six-1.10.0/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/usr/local/var/tmp/portage/dev-python/six-1.10.0/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/usr/local/lib/portage/pym'
 * S: '/usr/local/var/tmp/portage/dev-python/six-1.10.0/work/six-1.10.0'
}
```